# How to escape parenthesis in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - wondering how can I escape parenthesis in my query?

I'm trying to find the string position of "(" in one of my columns returned, but Management Studio keeps thinking I'm opening another command when I use that. I've tried \ but that isn't escaping it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this doesn't work for you?

```
select charindex('(', yourColumn)
from yourTable
```

Comment: It appears it does - I had another issue and the Management Studio wasn't showing corresponding closing parenthesis correct. When I use that, my next parenthesis doesn't show as closing out that function, but highlights the actual parenthesis I'm trying to find index on. Thank you.

Comment: @evanmortland: can you check the syntax once

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape it, see example below:

```
select charindex('(', x)
from (
    select 'asdasda(adsadas' as x
) a
```

**Output:**

8

Answer (score 1):

```
select charindex('(',<columnname>) from <tableName>
```